# Can we use "or" in bdd scenario

Tags: .net, bdd, specflow

```
Given I have a request \**8  
And   I create the following  match strength String in the \***  
|position    | Input String                                    |  
| 3 & 4      |  "NM" or "H1" or "S1" or "S2" or "L1" or "L2"   |  
| 9 to 13    | "Delphi Score"                                  |  
When I execute request ***
```

I am not sure if i can write scenario like this,i need to pass different values in 3 & 4 position ? let me know how can i pass different values in the same position ?

Thanks
DR

Comment: What values would you like to pass in? Can you write an example of the step you would like to write complete with test values?

Comment: I don't think you should put the exact string in the scenario description like that. What's the conceptual, business-understandable scenario you're trying to capture?

Comment: I would like to pass NM or H1 char in to 3 & 4 number position

Comment: In the transaction item ex: "MRNM234XXXXXXX" acceptance criteria:  Has a valid match strength result (i.e. one of the possible match strength scores such as 'NM' or 'H1') in positions 3 & 4

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, at lesat partly because your question has clearly lost some semantic formatting - e.g. the table structure.  Unfortunately we can't re-add the formatting without making possible incorrect assumptions about your question, so it would be better if you did it yourself.  

See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for instructions on how to apply markup to your question.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is:

Use multiple scenarios

Long version:

The process you are trying to follow is sometimes known as *Specification by example*. If you read up on this you will see that the aim is to test your scenarios with a reasonable number of examples that cover enough of the different code paths. The precise number of tests is up to you, but it should be less than the full set as covering every single occurence is too time consuming. Instead you are looking for reasonable business cases that get you towards your end goal of functioning software.

Now we choose Specflow becuase it can be used primarily in the business domain, i.e. we describe things in english, not in low level code. I would suggest that your example is far lower language level than suits Specflow, and that your scenarios are very long and detailed.

If you are able, try to rephrase your scenarios up a level. Think about what an `S1` or a `13` represent and hide the details from Specflow.

```
Given I have a new request to match series one delphi scores
When I execute my request
...
```

If you can't do that, then simply provide multiple scenarios for those key examples

```
Scenario: match S1 deplhi scores
  ...
Scenario: match NM delphi scores
  ...
```

etc

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you want in Specflow I don't believe.  But you might be able to change your scenario to a [scenario outline](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Using-Gherkin-Language-in-SpecFlow) and do something like this:

```
Scenario Outline:  
Given I have a '<request>'  
And   I create the following  match strength String in <position> with input string '<input string>'  
When I execute the '<request>'
Then I get result <result>
Scenarios:
|Request         |position    | Input String   |  result |
| "some request" | 3          |  "NM"          |  true   |
| "some request" | 4          |  "NM"          |  false  |
| "some request" | 3          |  "HI"          |  true   |
| "some request" | 3          |  "HI"          |  true   |
```

etc etc

Its difficult to be more specific as I don't understand enough about your domain from your question